# In asp.net are the queries generated at runtime?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to c # and asp.net/entity framework and in general to the concept of compiled language.

I wanted to know if, in asp.net, using the model and related functions to interact with the database, following a request the queries (which use variable values passed during the request) are generated at runtime or are they somehow precompiled together with the program itself?

What I would like to understand is if in an asp.net project using raw queries is still faster than using the model and therefore the or, in this case, nothing changes.

Comment: I think you are talking about *Entity Framework* and in that case, yes the query expression gets build at runtime

Comment: Both. The expression trees are compiled ahead of time, as they're regular C#, but the translation to queries happens at runtime. However, these translations are then themselves cached, so you typically only notice the overhead the first time. Note that compiling or interpreting queries is typically not the bottleneck of any program using a database, regardless of how you get them -- that would be the execution of the queries themselves. Whether "raw" queries are faster than what the ORM produces depends on the quality of the ORM (and the scenario).

Comment: as @Rahul said, Models based ORM is Entity Framework, not Asp.NET, maybe you should read some basics about Entity framework first.

Comment: A query is a Command Text which is a string.   The queries do NOT get generated at Run time, but the strings may get built at runtime.  Expression Tree may parse the inputs into a Command Text that gets used in the query.

Answer (score 2):

.net can make use of many libraries to connect to database. For example, you can use [System.Data.SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient?view=netframework-4.7.2)  to connect to sql server database and run sql command against it. [Entity framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/) is another library which can be used to connect to databases. This is a Object Relational Mapper (ORM) which generates queries dynamically, but you can also run sql statements against a database if you wish to using Entity Framework.